# indexedDB can't run on ios 8.1.1(with cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova

when I update my `iPad` from `7.1` to `8.1`，my application with `cordova` can't run.

Here is the code:

```
        if (typeof window.indexedDB == "undefined") {
            alert("Your system does not support indexdDB!")
        } else {
            var request, db;
            alert("window.indexedDB:" + window.indexedDB); // null 
            request = window.indexedDB.open("ios8", 2); // error
        }
```

But when I open it in browers(IE,chrome,safari), it works.
why the `indexedDB` is null?

Comment: Unfortunately at this time IndexedDB is not fully supported and is very buggy on iOS 8. You can take a look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb) to get a better idea of the support for IndexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved the problem now. 
I use shimIndexedDB(https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim)!

After it was required,add this code:

```
            if (!window.indexedDB) {
                window.indexedDB = window.shimIndexedDB;
            }
```

then everything is okey :)